# Dash App | f-string callback output won't display on new line ('\n')

Tags: plotly-dash

When I create the following dash app, the goal is to have each element included in the output from the callback display on a new line. However, when I run the app, each element is displayed on the same line. Images of the current output vs. desired output are imbedded after the code snippet.

Please share a solution and an explanation of why my code isn't providing the desired results:

```
app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id = 'dd_input', 
        options = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'], 
        value = ['test1', 'test2'],
        multi = True
        ),
    html.P(
        id = 'string_output'
        ) 
])

@callback(
    Output('string_output', 'children'), 
    Input('dd_input','value')
)

def test_func(dd_choice):
    string = ''
    new_line = '\n'
    
    for each in dd_choice:
        string += f'{each}{new_line}'
        
    return string
                       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

This is the output I keep getting that I DO NOT want:

[image]

The following is the desired output:

[image]

Attempts using append and join methods as suggested by stack responses. These solutions do not work:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're displaying this in a web page, you need to use `<br>` for line breaks or use a `<pre>` block. Otherwise the browser performs line wrapping.

Comment: Please explain how to integrate dash html components into my python function associated with the callback

Comment: I don't know dash, so I can't help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I had to figure out the answer to my own question. Here it is:

You append each string to a list and then add the dash html.Br component after each string in the list. Then you simply return the list after your loop has completed:

```
app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id = 'dd_input', 
        options = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'], 
        value = ['test1', 'test2'],
        multi = True
        ),
    html.P(
        id = 'string_output'
        ) 
])

@callback(
    Output('string_output', 'children'), 
    Input('dd_input','value')
)

def test_func(dd_choice):
    string = ''
    new_line = html.Br() # dash html component
    lst = [] # empty list

    for each in dd_choice:
        string = f'{each}'

        lst.append(string) # add string to list

        lst.append(new_line) # add line break after each string

    return lst

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<p>` for paragraph.
Try to use this:

Edit:

```
...
def test_func(dd_choice):
    strings = [html.P(option) for option in dd_choice]
    return strings
...
```

Comment: the .append() method doesn't work on strings.  And the Br() object has no attribute join. I've added screenshots of the resulting errors to my original question above.

Comment: So, I am making a correction in my code! Now, I believe that works fine.